# Correct way to import files in the same project in Go

Tags: go, goland

I have a Go project with a structure like this:

```
cmd
  myapp
    main.go
internal
  app
    myapp
      impl.go
```

Now in `main.go`, I want to import `impl.go`. GoLand tells me that I should do it like this:

```
import (
  "myproj/internal/app/myapp"
)
```

However, I compile the project on another machine (because I use EGL and that's not available on macOS). When I do

```
go build cmd/myapp/main.go
```

there, it cannot resolve the import. So I changed the import to use the full path of my github repo, like this:

```
import (
  "github.com/flyx/myproj/internal/app/myapp"
)
```

Code compiles fine now. However, after I pulled that back into GoLand, it cannot resolve the import anymore. Curiously, every item in the path gives a separate error, e.g.

> Cannot resolve directory 'github.com'

That's very strange since `github.com` is very obviously in my `$GOPATH/src` and other imports from there that are not my current project are working.

So… what am I doing wrong? I don't even understand how GoLand can resolve the path starting with `myproj`. I checked whether `GOPATH` is correctly set in GoLand and that's the case.

Comment: Is it a Go Modules project? If not is it located under `$GOPATH` on disk?

Comment: None of this should work. In Go one imports *packages*, not *files*. See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Library).

Comment: @Peter Sorry, screwed the paths during writeup out of habit. Actual code does import the packages, I fixed it.

Comment: @artspb The project is at `$GOPATH/src/github.com/flyx/myproj/` on disk. I am unsure what would make the project a *Go Modules project*; I do have a `go.mod` lying around, but I don't use it since the compiler on the target machine is too old.

Comment: @flyx Do you have Go Modules integration enabled under _Settings | Go | Go Modules (vgo)_? If yes then try switching it off.

Comment: @artspb That actually fixed it \o/. But why would it not import my package with that thing turned on? I use the whole path for external packages I import and it works just fine there.

Comment: @flyx What GoLand version do you use? There are some fixes for Go Modules projects under `$GOPATH` in the latest 2019.1.1.

Comment: @artspb `go version go1.12.1 darwin/amd64` on the dev machine and `go version go1.10.4 linux/arm64` on the target machine

Comment: @flyx Sorry, I was asking about GoLand. I've edited my message too late, apparently.

Comment: @artspb I just updated to 2019.1.1 but the problem stays the same when I enable module integration. If this is a GoLand bug, you can post your solution as answer.

Comment: @flyx It's hard to tell. I've just tried to recreate the problem but didn't succeed. It'd be great if you file a new issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/GO) where describe steps to reproduce or better attach an example project.

Comment: @artspb In my go.mod, there was `module myproj` instead of `module github.com/flyx/myproj`, that was the problem. I'll still open a bug report since I don't see why GoLang should fail that way in this setup.

Comment: Note I can't find the error you see (`Cannot resolve directory 'github.com'`) in the Go toolchain, which suggests that the error is in Goland, and not the Go toolchain (unless I missed it, of course).